# Css In Php not working

Tags: php, css

So this is the part of my code that I'm trying to make it work :

```
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($satt)){   
   echo "<li";

   if($row["satake"] == $fns ) {
       echo "class=\"selected\"";
   }
   echo "><a href=\"home.php?fn=".urlencode($row["satake"]).
   "\">{$row["satake"]}</a></li>";

   }
```

And upper in page I have defined these:

```
          <?php
  if (isset($_GET['fn'])){
      $fns = $_GET['fn'];
      $ys =   "";
  } elseif (isset($_GET['yosef'])){
      $ys =   $_GET['yosef'];
      $fns = "";
  }  else
  {
      $ys =   "";
      $fns = "";  
  }
?>
```

And this is the css :

```
.selected { font-weight: bold; }
```

It doesn't give me any error and it runs smoothly but doesn't work.

Comment: Could you include the HTML the PHP code is outputting when you run it?

Comment: You need a space between `li` and `class`

Comment: ohhhhhh godddddddddddd
it was the space thing 
i was steering at the monitor like idiots !
rep +++
tnx

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that you were missing an space, you might want to take these steps in the future to avoid this confussion:

1. PHP *is* a template engine. Use it as such (put PHP presentation INSIDE html, and not the other way around).
2. Check out the dynamic generated solution with the browser inspector (Chrome or Firefox).

So, your code becomes much more readable and easier to spot errors when you do:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($satt)){
  // Some light logic
  $satake = $row["satake"];
  $liclass = $satake == $fns ? "selected" : "";
  $cleansatake = urlencode($satake);

  // The presentation
  ?>
    <li class="<?= $liclass; ?>" >
      <a href="home.php?fn=<?= $cleansatake; ?>" >
        <?= $satake; ?>
      </a>
    </li>
  <?php
  } ?>
```

Comment: tnx , it was helpful , re factoring always helps but beginners like me tend to make it work fast rather than do it right .
excuse me for asking but i didnt understand this line :
$liclass = $satake == $fns ? "selected" : "";

i know what happens up until $fns , but '?; and beyond that lost me .

Comment: That would be a [ternary operator](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/3/12/4).